# Left Outer join JPA using Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteriaquery

I am stuck in a problem where I am not able to find out how to generate a **left outer join** on two tables using **criteriaQuery**.
I have two table A_1 and A_2

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "A_1")
public class A1 {
    private long id_1;
    private long name;
    private long city;
}

@Entity()
@Table(name = "A_2")
public class A2 {
    private long id_2;
    private long a_1_id_1;
    private long name;
}
```

**I have to find out all those entry which are present in A_1 table but not in A_2 table. id_1 in A_1 table is same as a_1_id_1**.

For this I am trying query like:

```
select * from A_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN A_2 ON A_1.id_1 = A_2.a_1_id_1 where A_2.a_1_id_1 is NULL
```

I am getting desired results from my query.
But I am not able to find out how Can I change it to code, basically this **left outer join part**. I have tried lots of options from net but unable to find out the solution.

My code is something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<A_1> root1 = query.from_1(A_1.class);
Root<A_2> root2 = query.from(A_2.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = getPredicates(cb, root1, root1, request);
```

I am not able to decide how can I use this to get my desired results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean, like using `join` method? rather than inventing a new root object

Comment: @BillyFrost : couldn't understand your point. I want to use normal left outer join

Comment: You use "normal left outer join" by using the `join` method in JPA Criteria! And you havent, you simply did `from` twice, and each one creates a root for the query (aka cross join). There are ample docs on the internet for this ... http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/query.html#_criteria_api_from_clause_joins  You join using relations, and you don't seem to have grasped that object-oriented point in your model

Comment: Thanks @BillyFrost : went through document and it was helpful.
Needs a little more help, is it possible to add null value in a predicate.
select o.o_id from orders_table as o left outer join pttt_table as p on o.o_id = p.o_id where p.o_id is null; this is my query I want to do same as this, but I am not able to understand  how can  I specify this null condition

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
final Root<A_1> a1 = criteriaQuery.from(A_1.class);
Join<A_1, A_2> join1 = a1.join("joinColumnName", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(A_2.<String> get("YOUR_COULMN"), value;
criteria.add(predicate);
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
```

Comment: how can I specify on which params I have made join  like ON in native query

Comment: really did not understand your question.. could you please make it more understandable

Comment: select o.o_id from orders_table as o left outer join pttt_table as p on o.o_id = p.o_id where p.o_id is null; 
this is my query I want to do same as this. but I didn't understand where you defined this ON condition.

Comment: My main concern is how can I specify this null condition